# Multiple join with self join in MySQL and split rows in columns by a row value

Tags: mysql

I have three tables "Users" , "Subjects" and "Marks" like

Users Table

```
id  name
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
6   A
7   B
```

Subjects Table

```
id  name
1   Chemistry
2   Physics
3   English
4   Maths
5   History
```

Marks Table

u_id is the foreign key of Users (id) and s_id is foreign key of Subjects(id)

```
id  u_id    s_id    marks
 1     1       1     60
 2     1       2     70
 3     1       3     80
 4     2       2     80
 5     2       3     44
 6     3       1     50
 7     5       4     50
 8     4       5     50
 9     5       4    100
10     2       5    100
```

and I wish for the result to be like

```
id  Name    Chemistry Physics English 
1   A       60        70      80
2   B       NULL      80      44
3   3       50        NULL    NULL
```

Using Join

So far I have only been able to get

```
name    name        marks
A       English     80
A       Physics     70
A       Chemistry   60
B       English     44
B       Physics     80
C       Chemistry   50
```

Using  the following query

```
SELECT u.name, s.name , m.marks
FROM Users as u 
RIGHT JOIN Marks as m ON m.u_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN Subjects as s ON m.s_id = s.id  
WHERE s.name = "English" 
  OR s.name = "Physics" 
  OR s.name = "Chemistry"
ORDER BY u.name; "
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the desired result as in get value of Marks in different columns.  I have use select u.name Name, s.name as Subject, m.marks as Marks
  from Users as u right join Marks as m on m.u_id = u.id left join
  Subjects as s on m.s_id = s.id  
  where s.name = "English" OR s.name = "Physics" OR s.name = "Chemistry"
  order by u.name;

Comment: Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @twitch, check if what I did is what you wanted, ;D

Answer (score 2):

Well, after reading the answers, I wanted to post my own one:

```
SELECT 
  u.id
, u.name

, MAX(IF(s.id = 1, COALESCE(m.mark), 0)) as 'Chem'
, MAX(IF(s.id = 2, COALESCE(m.mark), 0)) as 'Phys'
, MAX(IF(s.id = 3, COALESCE(m.mark), 0)) as 'Eng'

FROM marks m
INNER JOIN subjects s
ON s.id = m.subjects_id
INNER JOIN users u 
ON u.id = m.users_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

You can check that makes all you want in SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f567b/1

The important part is the grouping of all the elements according to the user id, and the way of writing the results from rows in a table to columns in another table. As written in @TheShalit answer, the way of achieving that is just assigning the value as a column. Problem is that when grouping by user, you'll have a lot of values there from where you have to select the important one (the one that is not 0 neither `NULL`, XD). `COALESCE` function makes sure that you always return a integer, just in case a `NULL` is given.

It's also important to notice that you'll have to build the SQL with the names of the subjects and the ids from database, as SQL can't retrieve the name of the elements to write them directly as names of the columns. That's why I wrote 'Chem', 'Phys' and 'Eng' instead of the right names. In fact, would be easier if you just wrote the id of the subject instead of a name, just to retrieve the elements later when you'll fetch the rows.

Take into account that is VERY IMPORTANT that you'll table will have the right indexes there. Make sure you have an `UNIQUE` id on the table `marks` with users and subjects to avoid having more than one value there stored

Comment: Thanks a lot I have been scratching my head for days in this. And the explanation helped me understand a lot and new features like "COALESCE" and the order of joining the tables

Comment: I´m glad to help, XD, I´ve also done a school application and I´ve had done similar queries. And if you liked it, accept it as the answer, ;D

Answer (score 1):

Use select like this(with joins and group by student):

```
MAX(If(subjects.name="Chemistry",marks.marks,'')) Chemistry,
MAX(If(subjects.name="Physics",marks.marks,'')) Physics,
.....
```

Comment: I like your grouping query, and he could do it that way, but why are you using a MAX? I think that only the IF will do the trick.

Comment: no.. it will only take the first row so if the first row is Chemistry, Physics will be an empty string

Comment: I got the answer without using max  SELECT u.NAME AS NAME,
       If(s.name="Chemistry",m.marks,'') AS chemistry,
       If(s.name="Physics",m.marks,'') AS physics,
       If(s.name="English",m.marks,'') AS english          
FROM Users AS u 
JOIN Marks as m on u.id = m.u_id
join Subjects as s on m.s_id=s.id;   Thanks :)

Comment: You need to use `group by u.name` as I said for one row for each student, and than you will need the `max`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like:

```
SELECT u.NAME AS NAME,
       m_e.marks AS english,          
       m_p.marks AS physics,
       m_c.marks AS chemistry
FROM users AS u 
JOIN marks AS m_e ON m_e.u_id = u.id 
JOIN marks AS m_p ON m_p.u_id = u.id 
JOIN marks AS m_c ON m_c.u_id = u.id 
WHERE m_e.s_id = 3 AND m_c.s_id = 1 AND m_p.s_id = 2
```

You are getting 3 different values from a single table but different rows so you need to join the marks table with itself to be able to get the values from 3 different records into 1 result row

I used the values that you defined as primary id's for your 3 subjects in your question in the where clause to make sure you are getting the correct result for each subject

Comment: This only gives me the value where all the subjects are present like user 'A' and not 'B' and 'C'